# Afnetworking for iphone and progress bar

Tags: progress-bar, afnetworking

Can we show an UIProgressBar while hitting the webservice. It is possible when we are uploading or downloading the files from server. 
Can it be possible without file?

Comment: Hey Ritesh- You should mark mattt's answer as correct since he was nice enough to answer you within 6 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`AFURLConnectionOperation -setDownloadProgressBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setDownloadProgressBlock%3a), updating the progress with the ratio of `totalBytesRead` over `totalBytesExpectedToRead` each time the block is called.